# Missing DLL even though it's in the directory with execuable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, c++-cli

On Windows7 in VS2012 I have a .NET 4.0 application (ModBusCdi75Api.exe) in C# with a wrapper for an unmanaged 3rd party C++ DLL.  My wrapper is written in C++/CLI.  The projects for both of these are in one VS2012 solution and the output directories for both projects point to the same Debug and Release directories.  Everything builds fine but on execution I get missing DLL error for the wrapper DLL (Cdi75LibM.dll).

[image: Exception Message]

The output directory where my ModBusCdi75Api.exe executable is has the Cdi75LibM.dll file.
[image: Output Directory]

I've run Dependency Walker on the Cdi75LibM.dll file and the only reported missing DLL's are GPSVC.DLL and IESHIMS.DLL which are 64 bit Microsoft DLLs and some [web research](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/93f8509b-b6e8-45a8-81a4-a7a127385d84/gpsvcdll-missing-from-cwindowssyswow64-in-windows-7-64-bit?forum=vcgeneral) tells me are not required.  My app, wrapper and 3rd party DLL are all targeted to 32 bit (x86). Also I have a previous very similar project which DependancyWalker also reports these same two files missing yet that application and wrapper runs with no error.  I wish there was a way to know if the problem is it can't find Cdi75LibM.dll or if it's one of Cdi75LibM's dependencies it is complaining about.  There must be something I've missed but I'm at a loss to see it currently.
[image]

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. You need the missing DLLs simply because the DLL you're loading/using explicitly links to the dependent DLLs whether their code is used or not.

Comment: Dependency Walker is no longer dependable.  Try the Fusion Logger mechanism, or watch your app with process monitor and see what files it tries to access.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz Did you see the part where I stated that I have a similar project where DependencyWalker reports the DLL wrapper as also missing these same two files but that application runs without a problem. To my understanding there is no 32 bit version of GPSVC.dll. Follow the web research link above to see discussion of this. I did find a 32 bit IESHIMS.dll but still get the same error. The failure occurs before the first line of my application executes. From what I can tell it's failing on the pre-load